# How to make a slash command bot do not reply messages

Tags: discord, command, discord.py, slash

```py
@slash.slash(name='spam', description='I will spam your content for times!', options=optionsspam, guild_ids=[847769978308526090])
async def spam(ctx, text: str, times: int="15"):
  if bool(times):
    Times = 15
  else:
    Times = times
  
  for i in range(int(Times)):
    await ctx.send(text)
    await asyncio.sleep(.7)
```

And the result is:

It keeps replying to the first message that the bot sent. I don’t want the bot to reply. I want it to just send a normal message. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An interaction (slash-command) will always require a direct response towards the user. If you do not use `ctx.send(str)`, the interaction will fail.

You've got 2 options to make it seem, like you are not responding to the slash command

##### Hide the response

You can post a hidden answer `ctx.send('ok', hidden=True)` and then send the intented message into the channel `ctx.channel.send(str)`.

This will make the initial 'ok' only visible for the invoking users and all other members of the server will neither see the request, nor the first response.

##### Delete the response

Your second option is to automatically delete the answer after a very short period (`ctx.send('ok', delete_after=1)`), followed by a normal message into the channel `ctx.channel.send(str)`.

##### Defering the response

You might need to `defer` your response if you can't respond within 3 seconds of the invocation. Defering an interaction (`ctx.defer(hidden=True)` or `ctx.defer()`) must be called with the same `hidden` attribute as your future `ctx.send()`.

If you want to hide your respons `ctx.send('ok', hidden=True)`, you need to defer in the same state `ctx.defer(hidden=True)`.

Comment: Thank you for answering me for very much details!

Comment: If you found a helpful answer which solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

You could get the channel and send message to the channel directly. However, you then must use something like `ctx.defer()` so that the interaction doesn't get displayed as failed.

```py
@slash.slash(name='spam', description='I will spam your content for times!', options=optionsspam, guild_ids=[847769978308526090])
async def spam(ctx, text: str, times: int=15):
  if ctx.channel:
    for i in range(times):  
        await ctx.send(text)
        await asyncio.sleep(.7)
  await ctx.send("Done")
```

Comment: (Edit applies to original post...)